# How to remove old static files in ASP.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, static-files

I added some audio files into wwwroot/audio, used them dynamically in different views, then I wanted to make some changes. After removing the first file (UserAudio001.wav) and renaming another file to UserAudio001.wav, after debugging in application there is still the older version of the audio. I removed all of the files and debugged the app, the UserAudio001.wav was still playing. 
It says that the source of the file is audio/UserAudio001.wav, it is possible to play sound from the url localhost:44329/audio/UserAudio001.wav, but from the Solution Explorer the audio folder is empty. The localhost:44329/audio url also says that there is nothing in audio folder. Cleaning the solution didn't work. Where can I find these older static files? I can't replace them with the new ones.

Comment: By any chance, have you tried to clear your cache?

Comment: @vvilin I haven't done this before. I've just removed ComponentModelCache and this didn't work. Should I clear something more?

Comment: Usually in your browser you can refresh the page without cache using `CTRL-F5`

Comment: Oh yes, I did this before. Didn't worked.